# BCH on Coinbase

Tags: bitcoin-cash, coinbase.com, gdax

I saw this message on Coinbase

> Update: We anticipate enabling Bitcoin Cash (BCH) buys and sells in
>   early January 2018. Sends and receives are online. If you held bitcoin
>   on Coinbase on August 1, 2017, y**ou should now see BCH in your Account.**

Does that mean "since" August 1? 'cause I have had Bitcoin since October on Coinbase but I **don't see any BCH on my account.**
However, I sent all my BTC to GDAX (Coinbase & GDAX should be the same).. But does that make the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It means "until August 1".

The history of the time until August 1 was copied. So the person who had your BTC at August 1, has the control of the BCH.

Answer (score 1):

They state you should hold BTC on August 1 and you held BTC since October. Because August comes before October, you did not have any BTC in your wallet on August 1 and therefore do not see any BCH in your account.

Comment: Yes, now sounds like a stupid question haha.
Made sense after I posted it but I wanted to be sure.

Now, if Coinbase supports a hardfork, should you move your coins from GDAX to Coinbase? Or is GDAX the same.